# How to select multiple button options on same html page using tailwind css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

This is what I have right now for the buttons wrapping around row/col wise in an HTML page. I intend for the user to be able to select multiple buttons at the same time

```
  <div class = "p-5">
    <button class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40">
      <div class = "text-left text-black font-bold">
        Hoppy
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class = "p-5">
    <button class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40">
      <div class = "text-left text-black font-bold">
        Fruity/Citrus
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class = "p-5">
    <button class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40">
      <div class = "text-left text-black font-bold">
        Roasty/Coffee
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
  
    <div class = "p-5">
        <button class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40">
        <div class = "text-left text-black font-bold">
            Chocolate
        </div>
        </button>
    </div>

<div class = "p-5">
    <button class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40">
      <div class = "text-left text-black font-bold">
        Not sure
      </div>
    </button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please share a working codepen/jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of clean up your code somewhat but to answer your question, you need javascript to achieve what you need.

I'm using AlpineJS which uses Vue like syntax but basically you need to add a class, to show the "selected" state for each button the user clicks.

Check the snippet below to see it in action:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.4.6/tailwind.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.3.5/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>


<div class="flex justify-center">
  <div class="p-5" x-data="{ active: false }">
    <button :class="{ 'bg-red-300': active }" class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40 text-left text-black font-bold" @click="active = !active">
      Hoppy
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="p-5" x-data="{ active: false }">
    <button :class="{ 'bg-red-300': active }" class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40 text-left text-black font-bold" @click="active = !active">
      Chocolate
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```